# How to send an invite to join a group inside my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an app where a user gets a list of people based on a the users search criteria. From the list the user is presented with a list of users currently searching for a group. I want to allow the user the ability to send an invite to a selected user on the list, thus forming a group from anywhere of 2 to 6 users. I am not sure where or what to research to achieve this goal. Also once the invite is sent and the users are in a group I want to have a feature for them to communicate with basic chat functionality.

So what I would like is some advise on what to look into for R&D to provide this functionality on my app. The app will be backed by a hosted MySQL database.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify a little more this is the basic flow I'm picturing in the app

1. Users sees a list of users and each list item has an invite button
2. The user clicks the invite button
3. The clicked user receives a notification of the invite and is allowed to either accept of decline
4. If ACCEPT the users are put into a group which will be stored on the server
5. Other users will be able to join the group
6. Users in the group can invite other users to the existing group
7. All the users in the group can communicate through a chat private to their group.

I just need to know how to get the sending of the  invite and accepting or declining of the invite started. What technologies to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u have to build an Backend Service. One Way could be to build an Rest Api with for example Node JS. You could define routes like invite user which takes a user id and group id. In the route function you would add the group id to the invitations of the user behind the user id. A other route could be accept invitation where you send a user id and group id. In the function you check if the user has a invitation of the group and if he had you add him in the group. But this is only a suggestion of nearly thousand possible ways. You could also add these kind of function in side your app. Instead of using the functions i had mentioned above as api routes just made them directly in the app. But then you have to notify the user if there is a new invite record in the database maybe with push notifications. But i would recommend to build a little server.

May look here a basic rest msql node js tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/ you would define here a route like

```
function inviteUser(req,res) {

pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
      return;
    }   

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

    connection.query("select req.body.userId from user",function(err,rows){
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            //ADD Group id to the user access the id with req.body.groupId
            res.json(rows);
        }           
    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {      
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;     
    });
  });
}

function acceptInvitation(req,res){

pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
      return;
    }   

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

    connection.query("select req.body.groupId from groups",function(err,rows){
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            //ADD user id to the group access the id with req.body.userId
            res.json(rows);
        }           
    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {      
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;     
    });
  });
}
}

app.get("/users/invite",function(req,res){-
    inviteUser(req,res);
});

app.get("/users/accept",function(req,res){-
    acceptInvitation(req,res);
});
```

From the App you will send http request on your server url like http://localhost:8080/users/invite with an body of { userId:xxxxx , groupId:xxxxx}

Comment: I appreciate your answer it gives me something to research. I have been researching for a day or two and not coming up with anything that seems viable.

Comment: i added some more hints may it will help you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: No worries I appreciate the help